# How to get rows from javascript array response?

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have skills in one table, user_skills in other table and getting skills against id from skills table in for loop.I have stored query results in javascript array. I want a array with objects in it. I'm getting array in array structure.  As you can see in image that i am getting multiple arrays in array.It should be objects in single array.

[image: response]

```
var userExist = await ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT * FROM USER_SKILLS WHERE user_id = $1",
            [`${user_id}`]);

        var strArray = userExist.rows[0].skill_array.split(",");

        var i;
        var skillsArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {

          var findSkill = await ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT skill_name FROM ALL_SKILLS WHERE id = $1",
                [`${strArray[i]}`]);

            skillsArray.push(findSkill.rows);

        }
        console.log('skillsArray', skillsArray);

        ctx.body = {
            status: 200,
            error: false,
            message: "Skills found",
            data: skillsArray
        };
```

Comment: share the exception you are getting.

Comment: This can be easily performed in one query, but you'd need to give more info about the structure: what data type is `skill_array`? If it's an actual postgres array, will it not include the `{}` characters at the beginning/end? (Assuming it comes into pg as a string, else why would you be splitting it?) And more generally, you'll have to tell us exactly what you mean by "not working". Error? Not returning the expected results?

Comment: can you add your table schema here? this would help a lot in fixing your error also as mentioned by @404 this should be in single database query using join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
var userExist = await ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT * FROM USER_SKILLS WHERE user_id = $1",
    [`${user_id}`]);

var strArray = userExist.rows[0].skill_array.split(",");

var i;
var skillsArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
  var findSkill = await ctx.app.pool.query("SELECT skill_name FROM ALL_SKILLS WHERE id = $1",
        [`${strArray[i]}`]);

    skillsArray.push(findSkill.rows[0]);

}
console.log('skillsArray', skillsArray);

ctx.body = {
    status: 200,
    error: false,
    message: "Skills found",
    data: skillsArray
};
```

But I as i mentioned in my comment, I suggest that you have your database tables/schema in relationships `M:M`, in your case, where you can just get the data you need in a single query, and it is considered bad practice to do a query in `for(...)` loop like this. you should use ORM like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/) or any other ORM that you prefer and works well with KOA, I hope this help you in achieving this:

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `skill_array` is in fact an array in postgres, you can combine both those queries into one:

```
const query = "SELECT skill_name
               FROM ALL_SKILLS
               WHERE id = ANY((
                   SELECT skill_array
                   FROM USER_SKILLS
                   WHERE user_id = $1
               ))";
const res = await ctx.app.pool.query(query, [`${user_id}`]);
```

That will be more performant than doing multiple queries.

Then the reason why you're getting an array with arrays is because `skillsArray.push(findSkill.rows)` puts the whole `rows` property, which is an array, into your `skillsArray` array.

It's not entirely clear to me exactly what is the format of the result you want, but I'll assume it's the actual skill names in an array, something like:

```
{
    message: "Skills found",
    data: [
        "PHP",
        "Node js"
    ]
}
```

In which case you could restructure your code to be something like this:

```
const query = "SELECT STRING_AGG(skill_name, ',') AS skill_names
               FROM ALL_SKILLS
               WHERE id = ANY((
                   SELECT skill_array
                   FROM USER_SKILLS
                   WHERE user_id = $1
               ))";
const res = await ctx.app.pool.query(query, [`${user_id}`]);
const skillNames = res.rows[0].skill_names.split(',');
ctx.body = {
    status: 200,
    error: false,
    message: "Skills found",
    data: skillNames
};
```

I've added a `STRING_AGG` because I like to get postgres results in a single row if possible rather than have `pg` read multiple rows sequentially, I believe it will be faster. I'm not using `ARRAY_AGG` because I don't know how the `pg` module treats arrays, whether it converts them to string or a js array. So I return one field with the skills concatenated with a comma, e.g. `"PHP,Node js"`, then just need to split that one field by the comma to get the desired array.